# Self-Editing Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

Here's my source code:

```
BUILD := 0001
VERSION := 0.00

COMPILER := g++
CFLAGS := 
LDFLAGS := 
EXECUTABLE := bin/conch$(VERSION)-$(BUILD).exe

all: src/conch.cc
    $(COMPILER) $(input) -o $(EXECUTABLE)

conch: obj/conch.o
    $(COMPILER) $(LDFLAGS) $(input) -o $(EXECUTABLE)

conch.o: src/conch.cc
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) -c src/conch.cc -o obj/conch.o

clean:
    rm -f obj/conch.o
```

How can I make the makefile so that when I `make conch` or `make all` the `BUILD` value increments?  Or is this not possible at all?

Comment: Store your build number in an external file, then read and write it as needed.

Comment: @muistooshort I know how to do that, it's what I've done up to this point.  I'm trying to reduce the number of files in my source code.

Comment: I would recommend against including the build number *inside* your makefile, because then the makefile itself gets an unnecessary change every time you commit. This will make the history for the makefile very noisy and it will be hard to find the real changes.

Comment: I agree with Greg.  Maybe you could generate a unique build ID based on date and time of build and include it in the executable somehow?

Comment: @japreiss That's a great idea. So you have any clue how I could do this?  I'm very new to makefiles, even though I've been programming c++ for the last five years...

Comment: I like to generate a build number from the version control system, although arguably that's linking two things that shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can "include" other files into a Makefile using, you guessed it, the [`include` directive](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include).

So you can have

### Makefile

```
include buildinfo.inc

COMPILER := g++
# ... etc
```

### buildinfo.inc

```
BUILD := 0001
VERSION := 0.00
```

Then, all you need to do is modify (or simply rewrite) `buildinfo.inc` to increment the version number. Those variables will then be usable inside your `Makefile` just as they are now.